# How to make a GRPC api call from javascript

Tags: javascript, grpc

I have an external 3rd party GRPC server running which I want to query it in my javascript code.

I was wondering if there is way to do it, just like we query REST api through node-fetch or axios ?

How do I make this api call through javascript

```
grpcurl \
    -plaintext \
    -d '{"attribute":"XX"}' \
    localhost:14190 \
    X.Y.Z/Something
```

Comment: Perhaps using something like this: https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/

Comment: @JensV To me it looks more like a lib to code grpc server. Could you give an example of how the above grpcurl can be converted to this ?

Comment: We do have a full fledged gRPC implementation in Node.js: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node

Answer (score 0):

The [Hello world client example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/greeter_client.js) for `@grpc/grpc-js` demonstrates how to make requests in general using the library. The specific components of the `grpcurl` invocation in the question correspond to the code in that example as follows:

- The `X.Y.Z/Something` service name corresponds with the name of the class that is instantiated to create the `client` object (`Greeter`, in that example).
- The `localhost:14190` argument corresponds to the address passed as the first argument to the `Greeter` constructor.
- The `-plaintext` option corresponds to the `grpc.credentials.createInsecure()` object passed as the second argument to the `Greeter` constructor.
- The `-d '{"attribute":"XX"}'` argument corresponds to the object passed as the first argument to the `client.sayHello` method in the example.